# setting the max-width property on CSS uncenter the elements in the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding a page with Bootstrap 3. I have a container and inside it I placed a row, split into 2 columns (col-6) with centered text (text-align: center on the parent, cascading to every child). The problem is one of these 2 columns is too wide since has more text than the other. I then set the max-width to render them equally but now on the screen they are pulled on the left part of the screen, not perfectly centered. How to center them again mantaining the max-width property?

HTML

```
  <div class="servizi services servizi_jumbotron">
    <br>
  <h1 class="servizi_title">Servizi Per i Privati</h1>     
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="servizi container">
      <p><b>GET ON BOARD</b> si occupa della formazione professionale e linguistica di giovani professionisti, orientati ad un mondo del lavoro sempre piu' competitivo ed internazionale. Mettiamo a disposizione per i privati numerosi servizi quali:</p>
      <br>
  </div>    
  <div class="servizi container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 service_box">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <li>Corsi individuali di formazione online e/o in presenza volti alla preparazione dei candidati a 
          sostenere colloqui di lavoro in lingua inglese.</li>
        <li>Corsi di inglese standard e commerciale a seconda delle esigenze del cliente..</li>
        <li>Corsi di lingua italiana per stranieri individuali o di gruppo, presso privati o aziende</li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 service_box">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <li>Preparazione di colloqui di lavoro per vari settori tra cui Pharma, Oil and Gas, Hospitality, Food & Beverage…</li>
        <li>Ottimizzazione di profili Linkedin</li>
        <li>Organizzazione di seminari e workshop formativi internazionali con docenti e ricercatori specializzati.</li>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.servizi_jumbotron {
    background: url("../images/students.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vw;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.servizi_title {
    font-size: 45px;
}


.service_box {
    max-width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're missing `<ul></ul>` tags.
You've used `col-md-6` class for *service_box* elements. That means below *md* they will use 100% of parent witdh. If you want to keep column width at 50% of parent then just use `col-xs-6` and add offset below *md*. You don't need to set `max-width`. Although I would rather make it bigger on smaller screens. Like this:

```css
.servizi_jumbotron {
    background: url("../images/students.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vw;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.servizi_title {
    font-size: 45px;
}


.service_box {
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="servizi services servizi_jumbotron">
    <br>
  <h1 class="servizi_title">Servizi Per i Privati</h1>     
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="servizi container">
      <p><b>GET ON BOARD</b> si occupa della formazione professionale e linguistica di giovani professionisti, orientati ad un mondo del lavoro sempre piu' competitivo ed internazionale. Mettiamo a disposizione per i privati numerosi servizi quali:</p>
      <br>
  </div>    
  <div class="servizi container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 service_box">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <ul>
        <li>Corsi individuali di formazione online e/o in presenza volti alla preparazione dei candidati a 
          sostenere colloqui di lavoro in lingua inglese.</li>
        <li>Corsi di inglese standard e commerciale a seconda delle esigenze del cliente..</li>
        <li>Corsi di lingua italiana per stranieri individuali o di gruppo, presso privati o aziende</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 service_box">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <ul>
        <li>Preparazione di colloqui di lavoro per vari settori tra cui Pharma, Oil and Gas, Hospitality, Food & Beverage…</li>
        <li>Ottimizzazione di profili Linkedin</li>
        <li>Organizzazione di seminari e workshop formativi internazionali con docenti e ricercatori specializzati.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's almost perfect, the problem is that when the screen is really wide (over 1250 px), the 2 columns are attached on the left and not perfectly centered. If I try to add col-lg-6 for the first and col-lg-offset-6 for the second, however, they stack one upon each other and in reverse position. any ideas? thanks in advance :)

Comment: ah sorry, it works, I forgot to remove the max-wdith property :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css display flex property to center "service_box". There are also other ways to make it center.

```css
.servizi_jumbotron {
    background: url("../images/students.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vw;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.servizi_title {
    font-size: 45px;
}


.service_box {
    max-width: 450px;
}
.flex-row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="servizi services servizi_jumbotron">
    <br>
  <h1 class="servizi_title">Servizi Per i Privati</h1>     
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="servizi container">
      <p><b>GET ON BOARD</b> si occupa della formazione professionale e linguistica di giovani professionisti, orientati ad un mondo del lavoro sempre piu' competitivo ed internazionale. Mettiamo a disposizione per i privati numerosi servizi quali:</p>
      <br>
  </div>    
  <div class="servizi container">
    <div class="row flex-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 service_box">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <li>Corsi individuali di formazione online e/o in presenza volti alla preparazione dei candidati a 
          sostenere colloqui di lavoro in lingua inglese.</li>
        <li>Corsi di inglese standard e commerciale a seconda delle esigenze del cliente..</li>
        <li>Corsi di lingua italiana per stranieri individuali o di gruppo, presso privati o aziende</li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 service_box">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <li>Preparazione di colloqui di lavoro per vari settori tra cui Pharma, Oil and Gas, Hospitality, Food & Beverage…</li>
        <li>Ottimizzazione di profili Linkedin</li>
        <li>Organizzazione di seminari e workshop formativi internazionali con docenti e ricercatori specializzati.</li>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that when I shrink the screen i want them to stack upon each other, like doing col-sm-12. When that happens, however, the 2 columns are pulled on the left, and not centered. How to solve it?